# Matplotlib: Reversing axis order based on coordinates given to pcolor/pcolormesh

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm building an application in which there is a colorplot plotted with `pcolor`. The user can apply various operations on this data like gradients, offsets and filters. One of these operations is a flip, where the x or y axis gets reversed. I represent every operation by a function which takes a matrix of datapoints and their x and y coordinates, and returns the same. I want to know if it's possible to reverse an axis with the data given to `pcolor`.

I have tried reversing the x/y coordinates but this will make matplotlib just reverse the data in the x or y direction in order to keep the axes positively increasing up and to the right.

So my question is as follows. Can I make `pcolor` reverse an axis so that it increases in the opposite direction when I supply a reversed `X` and `Y`. Or is there maybe a function option that I haven't seen yet?

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this,

```
pcolor(x, y, dat)
```

Then this should do what you want,

```
pcolor(y, x, dat.T)
```

In addition to swapping the `y` and `x` values, you must also to take the transpose (`.T`) of your data. This should work equivalently for [`pcolormesh`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh).

Comment: Maybe I didn't formulate it very clearly, I meant reversing the axis to make it go from positive to negative for example. I solved my problem by comparing the first and last coordinate and reversing the axes accordingly with `invert_xaxis()`.